# Magento 2: The command bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases does not work

Tags: magento2

I am having trouble using the magento i18n:collect-phrases command to collect phrases for translation.

When I use:

> php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o
>   "/app/i18n/test/xx_YY/dictionary.csv" -m

I get the error message:

> [RuntimeException] Not enough arguments

When I try to specify a location where to find phrases:

> php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o
>   "/app/i18n/test/xx_YY/dictionary.csv" /vendor/magento

I get the error message:  **[InvalidArgumentException]  Specified path doesn't exist**

I get the same message (Specified path doesn't exist) whichever path I chance the last part of the command into (app/design/frontend.... etc).

I took one csv file from one of the module categories, translated that into my language and tried to upload it using

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

This worked and showed translation on the frontend as well. But it doesn't have all the phrases and if I add phrases to that file manually, it does not show those phrases on the storefront.

The website that uses Magento is an addon domain, so the server category structure is:

> /home/Maindomain/addondomain/app, bin etc.

Could this be the reason why I am not able to collect phrases for translation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your file `/app/i18n/test/xx_YY/dictionary.csv` should be have four columns

1. The value of Translate
2. The value should be translated with this.
3. Module used simply `module`
4. Module Name of that particular translator e.g. `Magento_Catalog`

**e.g**

**`Save Category`   `Save Category New`    `module`    `Magento_Catalog`**

**AND**

```
[InvalidArgumentException] Specified path doesn't exist
```

for this, you have to collect translate variable from Magento2 Root

**use**

`php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "/app/i18n/test/xx_YY/dictionary.csv" Magento2ROOT/`

**instead of**

`php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "/app/i18n/test/xx_YY/dictionary.csv" /vendor/magento`

it will help you.

Comment: Thank you! It did work! I will just add that just **Magento2ROOT/** at the end of the code produced a file with two columns, but **-m Magento2ROOT/** produced the right file with four columns.

Comment: yes for that you have to create two more column e.g. `Save Category`  `Save Category New`  `module`  `Magento_Catalog` so. you have to create `module` and `Magento_Catalog` columns

Comment: when you try `php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "/app/i18n/test/xx_YY/dictionary.csv" Magento2ROOT/` in magento 2.0 you will get all four column but for magento 2.1 i dont know why its taking only 2 column.